# Compare values of two columns then select the larger value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to query a table and select 3 of the values of 4 columns. I need to compare the values of the 3rd column and the fourth column and select the larger value.

For example:

```
column1  column2  column3  column4
 hello    hello      3        5   
 hi       hi         7        1
```

I need to return:

```
column1  column2  Hybrid
 hello    hello     5   
 hi       hi        7
```

I have been trying to use IF/ELSE but I just can't seem to get the syntax correct

Comment: Column Hybrid values on result should be 5 and 7 correct?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In T-SQL the ***[IF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)*** command is for programatic control.  For example:

- `IF x THEN doSQLStatement1 ELSE doSQLStatement2`

Within a SQL statement, you need ***[CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)***.

```
CASE WHEN a > b THEN a ELSE b END
```

Comment: @MatBailie Even though I was look for something *a bit more* complex than this, I think you deserves a +1 for being so humble. Oh, and btw, you did manage to get ten up-votes;)

Answer (score 12):

Try this code:

```
SELECT column1, column2,
       (CASE WHEN column3 > column4 THEN column3 ELSE column4 END)
  FROM Table1
```

Result:

```
COLUMN1   COLUMN2  Hybrid
 hello     hello      5
  hi         hi       7
```

[Here you have complete sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/71b96/2) on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: SQL Fiddle example doesn't load.

Comment: Ufff!! seems that the sample is so old that was either lost, deleted or whatever

Answer (score 4):

You can use [CASE](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Content/SQL-Conditional-Expressions.htm#CASE), but if one of the values is 'null', the 'null' is considered the greatest value.

To solve this problem you can use [GREATEST](http://doc.nuodb.com/Latest/Content/SQL-Conditional-Expressions.htm#GREATEST)

```
SELECT GREATEST(column3, column4)
FROM Table1
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: OP is asking about MS-SQL Server's T-SQL dialect. `GREATEST` is not a function there.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating a view.

```
CREATE VIEW t_c
SELECT id, c1 AS c FROM t
UNION
SELECT id, c2 AS c FROM t;
```

Then I would select from that view.

```
SELECT id, MAX(c) FROM t_c GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: You'd have to justify that complication in terms of performance and/or maintainability. I suspect it's a loser on both fronts.

Answer (score 0):

Just so we don't return null:

```
SELECT  IIF( a > b, a, COALESCE( a, b )) -- coalesce or isnull
FROM wherever
```

Here's a query to test it:

```
with whatever as (
  select null as a, 1 as b
  UNION
  select 1 as a, null as b
  union
  select 1 as a, 0 as b
  union
  select 0 as a, 1 as b
  union
  select null as a, null as b
)
select( iif( a > b, a, isnull( b, a )))
from whatever
```

Should return

```
null
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: If you're using Oracle you can just use the GREATEST function.

Comment: `IIF` didn't exist for `sql-server-2008`, which is what the question is tagged as.

Answer (score -1):

```
select column1, coloumn2, case when column3 < column4 then column4 else coloum3 end from table.
```

Comment: Looks like you have a few spelling/syntax issues in that snippet.