# how to populate 3rd column in a table by using 1st and 2nd columns of max values

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table A, it has columns in following fashion:

```
COL1     COL2     COL3
 2        1
 4        6           
 10       8
```

My requirement is i've to insert values in 3rd column by using max values of col1 and col2(if col1 > col2 then value insert into col3 as col1 value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare values of two columns then select the larger value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057408/compare-values-of-two-columns-then-select-the-larger-value)

Answer (score 3):

The Oracle way of doing so would be:

```
UPDATE A SET COL3 = GREATEST(COL1, COL2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach would be simply update `col3` of your table with a result returned by the [greatest()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions052.htm#sthref1304) function:

```
update t1
  set col3 = greatest(col1, col2);
-- where clause if needed

select *
  from t1
```

Result:

```
      COL1       COL2       COL3
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          1          2
         4          6          6
        10          8         10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add COL3 as a virtual column:

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD COL3 AS ( GREATEST(COL1, COL2) )
```

It will cause your queries always up to date! No need to update.

Comment: It should work on Oracle 11g. http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-11g-new-feature-virtual-column/ Is there any problem with this query?

Comment: Ya, Its working. Thanks for the link, a new info :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET COL3= case when COL1>COL2 then COL1 else COL2 end
```